# Where do I use (and not use) "that?" (not a vs. "this" question)

Tags: grammar, writing-style

Given this sentence, the *that* **feels** unnecessary:

> If I believed that I were in a position to do so, I would.

I find these seemingly spurious instances of *that* working their way into my prose all the time.

Another example where it seems unnecessary:

> I've been around people so critical that I ceased hearing them.

My question is: What is the grammatical basis determining where *that* is appropriate in sentences like these?

Comment: You must have been a French speaker in a former life. Me too. Only I don't think all those "that"s are necessarily spurious. The first one is optional and _was_ should be _were_, but the second one isn't optional for me: the sentence sounds incomplete to me without it. I'll wager that most native speakers will call both optional, though. So many sloppy speakers and writers produce sloppy, slippery English.

Comment: Yeah, the was/were sentence is from a quick draft [fixed]. Mea culpa. I wish I were a French speaker in *this* life!

Comment: It's easy enough to learn French. Start now!

Comment: To the editor: style guides differ when it comes to the capitalization of an independent clause following a colon. Just sayin'.

Comment: You're right about that. But we all have our biases and preferences, so you have to be prepared for that kind of edit here. 'Shappened to me a few times too.

Answer (score 3):

> We can omit **that** in all positions, except when the **that** goes
>   at the beginning of a sentence . . . or when the **that**-clause comes
>   after an abstract noun . . . We usually omit **that** in speech.

[‘An A-Z of English Grammar and Usage’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0582405742) by Leech and others.

In relative clauses, *that* is usually omitted unless it is the subject.

*If I were* and *if I was* are both grammatical in British English, but not, apparently, in American English.

Comment: That's pretty close to everything. There are reasons for this behavior, but they're much more complex.

Comment: So, the "the nothing that was there" is grammatically sound and the "that" in my example sentences should both be omitted?

Comment: @JohnLawler Go on, then.

Comment: @Chris. _Can be_ rather than _should be_.

Comment: @Chris: No, _that_ in your examples ***may*** be deleted. There is no ***should*** involved -- Complementizer _that_ is optional in this configuration, is all.  Relative marker _that_ has other optional configurations, but this isn't one of them, because it's not a [relative clause](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/xmasthat.html).